# finding the missing value for ValueError: need more than X values to unpack

Tags: python, error-handling, variable-assignment, iterable-unpacking

I have a function call that looks like this:

`a,b,c,x,y,z = generatevalues(q)`

Its in a try block to catch the error but I also need to find out which value is missing. I can't clear the variables beforehand either. I'd also rather not merge the 6 variables inside the function into a list and pass it, but other than that is there a way of finding out which variable(s) are missing?

Comment: Well, it will always be *missing* the variables starting at the end since you are unpacking a tuple or list.  If you get back 5 values from `generatevalues(q)` then you will be missing `z`.  If you get back 4, you will be missing `y` and `z`.

Comment: Why does `generatevalues` return an arbitrary number of these values? Also, why do you need to unpack them?

Comment: So if generatevalues returns 4 items, you wish to define a,b,c,x and not y,z? This is not a very good pattern to use generally

Comment: no the function is supposed to return 6 values but I'm trying to debug it.

Comment: @incognito2: In that case, just capture the resulting iterable: `values = generatevalues(q)`. Now, you can look at what `values` is and if it has six items.

Comment: @incognito2, is it a generator, or does it just return a tuple? Look out for places where it might be returning `None`. Especially dropping off the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
values = tuple(generatevalues(q))
try:
    a, b, c, x, y, z = values
except ValueError as e:
    print(len(values)) # for example
    print(values)
```

To *debug* this function - it's a good time to learn about the [debugger](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)

```
values = tuple(generatevalues(q))
try:
    a, b, c, x, y, z = values
except ValueError as e:
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Comment: Good answer, but you might want to explain the simple `print values` possibility for quick&dirty debugging. It may seem obvious, but it may not be to a novice.

Comment: Also, I'd use the new-style `except ValueError as e:` instead of the deprecated `except ValueError, e:`. More novices are likely to need 3.0+ support today than 2.4-.

Comment: the thing is the error happens randomly and I wont be around most of the time so right now I just have it in a try block and was planning to write info about the error in a logfile.

Comment: @incognito2: So just use gnibbler's first version, then put the `logging.error('Exception {!r} unpacking {!r} as 6 values'.format(e, values))` (or whatever log function you use) into the `except` where he has the ellipsis. Then you'll see whether you had `None`, or 5 values instead of 6, or the string representation of a 6-element tuple instead of the tuple itself, or…